# Unable to setup Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android

I installed Android Studio 3.0.1 and everything seemed to go as expected. When first starting up, I got to the point of downloading the SDK components, and received the following error.

"Android Support Repository, Android SDK Tools and 7 more SDK components were not installed"

Has anybody every seen this? Any ideas or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

I am using Windows 10 64 bit. I was able to capture some more details of the failure.

"java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Users\gcleveland\Documents\Android\SDK2\extras\android\m2‌​repository.backup.i‌​nstaller.installDat‌​a -> C:\Users\gcleveland\Documents\Android\SDK2\extras\android\m2‌​repository.installe‌​r.installData Warning: Failed to move original content of C:\Users\gcleveland\Documents\Android\SDK2\extras\android\m2‌​repository back into place! It should be available at C:\Users\gcleveland\Documents\Android\SDK2\extras\android\m2‌​repository.backup"

There are multiple other instances like this but different directories.

It is almost as if my permissions are not correct. I have full administrative rights and run android studio as an administrator.

Comment: What are you trying to install it on? Windows 10? Windows 7? Mac (version?)? A Commodore 64?

Comment: Was there an earlier line giving a reason for not installing?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issues with the `exe` file version and resolved them by instead downloading and installing the `zip` version of Android Studio 3.0.1 for Windows 10 (https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/3.0.1.0/android-studio-ide-171.4443003-windows.zip). After unzipping this file, I simply executed its bin/studio64.exe. I also switched my networking connection to NOT need a proxy, which may also have helped to resolve the issue.